# Handler doen't invoke if we configured the asp.net site as ip and execute another machine

Tags: asp.net, http, httphandler, ihttphandler, httphandlerfactory

I have added the HTTP handler in local machine. I configured the site ip based. I try to invoke the handler in remote machine. I couldn't.
It doesn't call.

Please help me...

Comment: namespace Sample
{

    public class SamHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
   }
  }
 }
}

Web.config:

<add name="sam*" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="Sample" modules="ManagedPipelineHandler" scriptProcessor="" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="" />

Comment: please confirm any verb that we missed in web.config

Comment: that i mention above. I have declare it web.config. if i run any page. It automatically invoke. in local machine, it is working fine. I invoke remote machine. It shouldn't be..